# How to get in dialogflow side phone number shared by user in telegram chatbot

Tags: dialogflow-es, telegram, chatbot, phone-number

I am coding chatbot using dialogflow. Dialogflow is integrated with telegram. I would like to receive the phone number from chatbot user. 
This code I am using works very well. I see the button in telegram. Pressing of button shows the phone number. But actual problem is, that I am not receiving the phone number in dialogflow side?

Could you recommend something?

I am using following code to send request:

```
let payload2 = new Payload(agent.TELEGRAM, {
    "text": text + ' ⏬',  
    "reply_markup":  {
            "one_time_keyboard": true,
            "resize_keyboard": true,
            "keyboard": [[{

              text: text2,
              callback_data: "phone",
              request_contact: true
            }]]
        }   


});  
agent.add(payload2);
```

I am expecting to receive in dialogflow side the phone number which was sent by user of chatbot.

Comment: Common, any ideas? Or question should be reformulated?

Answer (score 0):

```js
    
    
    let payload2 = new Payload(agent.TELEGRAM, {
        "text": text + ' ⏬',  
        "reply_markup":  {
                "one_time_keyboard": true,
                "resize_keyboard": true,
                "keyboard": [[{
    
                  text: text2,
                  callback_data: "phone",
                  request_contact: true
                }]]
            }   
    
    
    }, { sendAsMessage: true, rawPayload: false });  
    agent.add(payload2);
```

Comment: Consider adding some text explaining the difference between your answer and OP's original code, and how this difference solves OP's problem.